# Why can't I plot two graphs on the same plane in WolframAlpha?

Tags: wolfram-alpha-queries

When I plot these graphs separately everything is OK, but when I try to plot them simultaneously I get error. Why?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: W|A can plot this, but it apparently chokes on the interpretation as given. `ContourPlot[{x^2 + y^2 == 6, x ArcTan[x] - x + y ArcTan[y] - y == 0}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]` gives the expected result on W|A, but if you're using _Mathematica_ already there's no reason to call W|A to do that plot since _Mathematica_ can do it directly. Is there a reason you're trying to use W|A specifically here, or perhaps are you trying to investigate error handling with respect to W|A queries?

Comment: It was just interesting for me why W|A can't do this, I've tried different versions of input and these are quite simple functions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
WolframAlpha["plot x^2+y^2=6 and x arctanx -x +y arctan y=0"]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It seems the spaces were to blame.